# External dll in custom workflow Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I created a workflow and i am using some external dlls. How to register them in crm 2013 online, because when i try to run workflow it gives me error. Will i have to merge the dlls? or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use ILMerge to include referenced assemblies to output assembly. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/11/09/how-to-reference-assemblies-from-plug-ins.aspx) describes how to do it.